# react-router v5 - withRouter renders blank screen

Tags: reactjs, react-router

After updating react-router and react-router-dom to v5.0.0 (from v4.3.1), my withRouter hoc does not render the App Container Component at all. It fails to render anything and I don't get any warnings/errors.

**index.js**

```
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
<Provider store={store}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <AppContainerComponent />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>
```

**AppContainer.component.js**

**imports** -

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';
```

**renders** -

```
<AppRoutes isAuthenticated={isAuthenticated} />
```

**exports** -

```
export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps)(AppContainer));
```

**appRoutes.component.js**

```
<UnauthenticatedRoute
      path="/"
      exact
      component={SignupComponent}
      isAuthenticated={isAuthenticated} />

<AuthenticatedRoute
      path="/app"
      exact
      component={AppComponent}
      isAuthenticated={isAuthenticated} />
```

These hoc's will either Redirect to the path if user is authenticated or will render the SIgnupComponent.

The AppComponent has bunch of routes defined by Route component as -

```
<Route exact 
       path="/path1"
       render={} 
/>
...
```

With all this configuration, the appContainer component does not render at all. It used to work just fine when I was using v4.3.1 of react-router.

**I am using preact (v8) with preact-cli(v2)**

Comment: what is the code for the components `UnauthenticatedRoute` and `AuthenticatedRoute` ?

Comment: @OlivierBoissé The 'UnauthenticatedRoute' and 'AuthenticatedRoute' custom HOCs and  will either Redirect to the path if user is authenticated or will render the SIgnupComponent.

Comment: do you have an error in the console ? If you render an simple react element like `<div>test</div>` in `AppContainer`, do you see somthing on the screen ?

Comment: only blank screen, no error message